# Print Unity Coordinates to a string at specified time interval

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, file-io, 3d

I want to move a cube using some device and periodically (every 3 seconds) print those coordinates to a file. I am not sure how to accomplish this with my code below.  Does anybody have ideas as to how this can be done?

Thank you!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]

public class UserController : MonoBehaviour {

    public int speed = 20;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // get input data from keyboard or controller
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        // update player position based on input
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        position.x += moveHorizontal * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        position.z += moveVertical * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = position;
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            float distance_to_screen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;
            transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance_to_screen));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to print coordinates every 3 seconds? or Only if you are holding something and print at the end of every three seconds during the hold time?

Comment: Basically print coordinates every 3 seconds. @killer_mech

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a separate script and attach it to your cube.

```
public class CubeTracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool logging = true;

    void  Awake()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LogPosition());
    }

    private IEnumerator LogPosition()
    {
        while (logging)
        {
            Debug.Log(transform.position);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        }
    }
}
```

This will start a coroutine as soon as the cube is created and should log your desired result into console. If that's what you desire, you can then go ahead and replace the Debug.Log with a write-to-file implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable, and feed it inside `Update()` method.

for example:

```
private Vector3 LastCoordinate{get; set;}
```

and the use a periodic timer like :

```
private System.Threading.Timer timer;
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(GetLastCoordinate, null, 3000, 0);

private void GetLastCoordinate()
{
    lock(this)
    {
        Vector3 lastCoordEachThreeSecs = LastCoordinate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, but how would I print the coordinates to a for this, though? If I try to call a method to print the coordinates in update, it prints a bunch of ridiculous points (0,0,0)... Any idea on how to do that, please?

Comment: @I Debarshi yeah when you call it inside update it prints with tge speed of your FPS. The idea of using periodic timer is to prevent such a behavior. Then you can use Debug.WriteLine() to print in output window of VS